# Zipping Files and Downloading them Using SaveAs Dialog

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code to zip all the files and then save it to the harddisk. I want zip all the files (this is done) and then attach the zip file to the Response stream so that the user have the option to save it!

```
protected void DownloadSelectedFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = String.Empty;
            string zipFilePath = @"C:\MyZipFile.zip";

            ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(zipFilePath));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvFiles.Rows)
            {
                bool isSelected = (row.FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox).Checked;

                if (isSelected)
                {
                    path = (row.FindControl("lblUrl") as Label).Text;

                    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(path));
                    entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

                    zipStream.PutNextEntry(entry);

                    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
                    {
                        int sourceBytes;
                        do
                        {
                            sourceBytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            zipStream.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);
                        } while (sourceBytes > 0);
                    }
                }
            }


            zipStream.Finish();
            zipStream.Close();

            Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=SS.zip");
            Response.WriteFile(zipFilePath);
            Response.End();

        }
```

Comment: Every time I download the ZIP file it is corrupted!

Comment: is the zip file corrupted on disk as well?

Comment: no Zip file is not corrupted. I have 3 text files which I create them into a single zip file and then download it but it says corrupted. If I save it on hard disk then it opens fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I blogged about sending files like this a while ago. You might find something usefull in there.

http://absolutecobblers.blogspot.com/2008/02/downloading-and-deleting-temporary.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are  using IE, check that its not the old "cache is full"-bug that is showing its ugly face.

And if you have IE set to refresh cashe Automatically or on IE-start and have downloaded that zip-file broken the first time, then it could be that it uses the cached version of that zip-file after you fixed your routine and got a good zip.

Try to add:

```
  Response.Buffer = true;
  Response.Clear();
  Response.ClearContent();
  Response.ClearHeaders();
```

before your Response.ContentType 
and add this:

```
Response.Flush()
Response.Close()
```

before response.end, and see if that changes anything.

So the result is this:

```
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";  
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=SS.zip");  
Response.WriteFile(zipFilePath);  
Response.Flush()
Response.Close()
Response.End();
```

Just some tips just from the top of the mind.

Comment: Tried it the same result. The zip file is corrupted!

Answer (score 0):

And a long shot, try set the mime type to application/unknown, in this post there seems to be part of the solution to the posters problem:

http://jamesewelch.com/2008/12/03/sharpziplib-and-windows-extraction-wizard-errors/

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to save the zip file to the server folder and then giving a link to the user to download it but it says the same "The file is corrupted". This is very strange since I can open the same folder if I visit my server folder and manually open it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another thing I found. If I save the zip file in the Server's folder and then reference it using the url: http://localhost/MyApplication/ServerFolder/MyZipFile.zip.

If I go to the url and download the zip file I get the same error "File is corrupted". But if I manually go to the folder using file explorer and open the file then it works as expected.

Why and How?

Comment: Tried to use another browser? I have seen different results with different browsers when other had that problem. And if IE, clear the cashe and try again.